# Does adding new fields (and/or methods) break OCP (open closed principle)?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

Let's say I have an XML file structure to import to a database:

```
<Flight>
    <FlightName>FN 7777</FlightName>
    <Passengers>
        <American>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        </American>
        <American>
            <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
            <LastName>Brown</LastName>
        </American>
        <German>
            <FirstName>Hans</FirstName>
            <LastName>Schaefer</LastName>
        </German>
        <Ukranian>
            <FirstName>Sergei</FirstName>
            <LastName>Osipenko</LastName>
            <CanSpeakRussian>true</CanSpeakRussian>
        </Ukranian>
    </Passengers>
</Flight>
```

Based on initial requirement I created this class structure:

```
public class Flight
{
    public Flight()
    {
        Passengers = new List<IPassenger>();
    }
    public string FlightNr { get; set; }
    public List<IPassenger> Passengers { get; set; }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
         ...
    }

}

public interface IPassenger
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class German : IPassenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class American : IPassenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Ukranian : IPassenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool CanSpeakRussian { get; set; }
}
```

In the second release of the project, we had 3 new requirements:

1. Flight must have a Destination node
2. All passengers must have a Passport Number
3. All American passengers must have SSN (social security numbers)

The XML structure of these requirements is:

```
<Flight>
    <FlightName>FN 7777</FlightName>
    <Destination>Chicago</Destination>
    <Passengers>
        <American>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <PassportNr>US123456</PassportNr>
            <SSN>123-45-6789</SSN>
        </American>
        <American>
            <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
            <LastName>Brown</LastName>
            <PassportNr>US556699</PassportNr>
            <SSN>345-12-9876</SSN>
        </American>
        <German>
            <FirstName>Hans</FirstName>
            <LastName>Schaefer</LastName>
            <PassportNr>DE112233</PassportNr>
        </German>
        <Ukranian>
            <FirstName>Sergei</FirstName>
            <LastName>Osipenko</LastName>
            <CanSpeakRussian>true</CanSpeakRussian>
            <PassportNr>UK447788</PassportNr>
        </Ukranian>
    </Passengers>
</Flight>
```

**Question-1: 
If I change the code structure as below, does it break Open Close Principle of SOLID?**

```
public class Flight
{
    public Flight()
    {
        Passengers = new List<IPassenger>();
    }
    public string FlightNr { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public List<IPassenger> Passengers { get; set; }
}

public interface IPassenger
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string PassportNr { get; set; }
}

public class German : IPassenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PassportNr { get; set; }
}

public class American : IPassenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PassportNr { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

public class Ukranian : IPassenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool CanSpeakRussian { get; set; }
    public string PassportNr { get; set; }
}
```

**Question-2: 
Do you think that I should use abstract class for this structure for better and shorter code? If so, is there any negative implication for testability?**

```
public class Flight
{
    public Flight()
    {
        Passengers = new List<Passenger>();
    }
    public string FlightNr { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public List<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }

}

public abstract class Passenger
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PassportNr { get; set; }
}

public class German : Passenger
{
}

public class American : Passenger
{
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

public class Ukranian : Passenger
{
    public bool CanSpeakRussian { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you worried about, following SOLID to the tooth or complete your job requirement? What you have is a new requirement.  Adding property is not breaking any rules. Even if you do have consumers of your code out there, who refers your code, adding property to a class will not hurt unless you changing interface [as you discovered]. You need to ask yourself a question, who is using your code? If this is just internal code and you have control of full base - you can do anything. If you want to support backwards compatibility in many cases, you need to use abstract classes.

Comment: @T.S. Actually, I'm just trying to understand the open/closed principle. I prepared this example to understand the boundaries. As far as I can understand from several articles, even Jon Skeet has some issues with this principle ([refer this link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/03/15/the-open-closed-principle-in-review/)).

Comment: All programming patterns, principles and dogmas have criticism. You don't really have to follow any of these to the point. It is useful though, if you explain to someone how something works that you have a sub-system developed using P-pattern, bla-bla, they understand you. Just look at .NET framework to understand o-c principle better. .NET in many cases has Interface and abstract class. So you can write fully custom implemented object or rely on base implementation given to you. But then it is up to you, do you want to leave YOUR object open or closed - sealed class.

Comment: If you write extendable framework for your consumers, so they can customize behavior of the base product - this is when you need to take care of things according to o/c principle. If you have code that you don't expect anyone to extend, you need not worry about. This is the bottom line

Comment: @T.S. My intention is not to discuss if the SOLID, DRY, YAGNI or others are good or bad. All I want is to understand the boundaries of OCP principle. Question is simple. Adding a few fields and/or methods break the open closed principle or not? Open to extension but close to the modification implies what exactly? Is adding a field and method an extension or a modification?

Comment: If your class implements Interface - it is closed to modification. If you change interface - you need to change all the classes that implement it. If your class derives from abstract class, it is open for modification because you can add a method without hurting anyone. *A module will be said to be open if it is still available for extension*. Your abstract class is open for extension. .Net went even further with O/C - extension methods. This leaves practically anything open to modification (or sort of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote from Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices by Robert Martin (must read):

> Modules that conform to OCP have two primary attributes.
>
> They are open for extension. This means that the behavior of the
>   module can be extended. As the requirements of the application change,
>   we can extend the module with new behaviors that satisfy those
>   changes. In other words, we are able to change what the module does.
>
> They are closed for modification. Extending the behavior of a module
>   does not result in changes to the source, or binary, code of the
>   module. The binary executable version of the module—whether in a
>   linkable library, a DLL, or a .EXE file—remains untouched.

(Note that when it says “module”, it doesn't necessarily mean an assembly of some sort, but also smaller-scale things like classes and compilation units.)

What's important here is that it's about *behavior*. What you have there is a hierarchy of data structures, more or less void of any behavior. So as it stands, it's hard to say whether your code violates OCP or not, as it's not exactly applicable.

Violations of OCP usually come together with some type-based switches or conditionals. Does any behavior of the `Flight` class depend on what type of passengers it has? If so, it could come in different shapes, such as:

```
if (passenger is Kefiristani) {
    performSuperStrictSecurityChecks(passenger);
}
```

or move this ugly code into the `performSecurityChecks` method of the `Passenger` class, and then in the `Flight` class just do

```
passenger.performSecurityChecks(); // non-virtual call
```

Or just do it the OOP way, hurray polymorphism!

```
passenger.performSecurityChecks(); // virtual call
```

Now suppose a new class of passenger, `Tumbombalooni`, appears, which also requires Super Strict Security Checks. In the first two cases you have to change some code outside of the new class, and that precisely what is meant by that they are *not closed.* In the last case, you don't have to change anything.

The first example violates SRP, of all things. It may also violate OCP on the assembly level, if your classes are not internal, and someone *outside* of your assembly may extend them, and now they have to go change your code to make it work. If they are internal, then it's debatable whether it violates OCP or not, but the violation of SRP is even worse anyway.

The second example definitely violates OCP. Extending a class should not force authors of the derived class to change anything in the base classes. In fact, they may not be able to.

The last example doesn't violate OCP. The class is still extendable, and extension doesn't require modifications, just writing *new* code. That's what OCP is all about.

To answer your original question: does adding new fields (and/or methods) break OCP? No, by itself it doesn't. But when adding or changing something in a derived class forces you to make some changes to the base class(es), then OCP is broken.

One thing about OCP is that it's virtually impossible to never ever break it at all. A certain requirement for a derived class may force you to change something in a base class anyway. If you plan ahead for every possible such change, you risk over-engineering everything, and then something you didn't think of comes and bites you anyway. But when it happens, you could deal with it in different ways, and it's better to add a virtual method to the base class just once and then reimplement this method in new derived classes, rather than falling into the same trap again and again, until your code becomes effectively unmaintainable.

Comment: Last paragraph is the best. everything comes down to "who's the code keeper" and is it designed to be extended to begin with. da?

Comment: I know it's a long time ago post, but maybe someone can help me about it.If I have to add a new database column. The governmanet changes the law we need need to persist a new attribute to the database. It's ok about modifying the entity?